# WebAPI found reference error when I have the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've created a MVC 4 Web API Application inside my solution, but I'm getting 2 errors right now and I need some help.

> 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for
>   'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' and no extension method
>   'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

This error occurs on the following code

**File: WebApiConfig.cs (at App_Start folder)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;

    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Another one, is in the Global.asax

> 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Configure'

**File: Global.asax.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.WebHost;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

After installing via Nuget the WebAPI WebHost (suggestion of @sa_ddam213) it resolves some problems, but now a got this error when run my application

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference

**Web.config file has the assembly**

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: are you sure you have System.Web in your projects "References" folder?

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson Yes, I updated my question with a image where we can see some references that exist in this project

Comment: @Lucas_Santos can you check your web.config for some assembly redirects ?

Comment: have you installed  `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` pretty sure you can just nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`

Comment: @nsgocev Seems everything ok with my Web.config file, and normally (we expect) that every changes in the file, was done by .NET and not a people doing some reference manually there.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Good, this resolve some problem, but when I run my application, a got this error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference`

Comment: I uninstall some nuget packages in my project, including the MVC, and install all over again. Resolved. Thanks everybody for help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I uninstall some nuget packages in my project, including the MVC, and install all over again. Resolved. Thanks everybody for help me.

Answer (score 103):

A forced reinstall of WebAPI could do the job:

```
 update-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi -reinstall
```

Answer (score 14):

I did:

```
get-project <project_name> | uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -force
```

Then reinstalled (with specific version consistent with those in other projects)

```
get-project <project_name> | install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -Version 5.2.2
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7):

Please try updating your packages by running the following command on `nugetmanager` console

```
update-package microsoft.aspnet.webapi.webhost -reinstall
```

Answer (score 6):

Update Your NuGet Packages. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check in your solution folder packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45 has System.Web.Http.dll is available or not. It should be there. If not available copy it from any other running project packages folder.
2) Remove reference of System.Web.Http.dll from your project.
3) Add new reference by pointing to new .dll that is to packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for me, I downloaded from TFS someone at works solution and got the error

```
System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' and no extension method 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes'
```

I was **ABOUT TO** go ahead with the re-install of web api, but I know past experiences that the dependency chain of the order in which you install items you can end up with a bit of drama.

JSON is hit or miss as sometimes I seen updated JSON force and uninstall of a newer version of another package and install an older version as it thought "it knew best.

For me   **UPDATE JSON** via nuget  was all i had to do.